# Quoting previous correspondence - correct formatting

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am writing a service(Spring Integration + JavaMail API) that automatically replies to a received message and I am having problems with including the previous message body.

How can I handle it correctly? I'd like to keep the same formatting, the one that Gmail/Thunderbird uses. I included code snippets showing how I've done it, but is there perhaps some other solution I could use? Some library, perhaps? Regular expressions? I sweeped through stackoverflow questions, but answers telling me that I have to handle it on my own aren't exactly helpful.

I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

On Gmail it looks like this:
[image]

Thunderbird:

[image]

```
fun prepareReplyFor(mimeMessage: MimeMessage): MimeMessage
{
    val response = mimeMessage.reply(SHOULD_REPLY_TO_ALL) as MimeMessage
    val mailFormatter = MailFormatter()

    val botText = MimeBodyPart()
    botText.setContent("This message was generated.\n", "text/plain")

    val previousCorrespondence = MimeBodyPart()
    previousCorrespondence.setContent(mailFormatter.formatPrevious(mimeMessage), "text/plain")

    val responseBody = MimeMultipart()
    responseBody.addBodyPart(botText)
    responseBody.addBodyPart(previousCorrespondence)

    response.setContent(responseBody)

    return response
}
```

MailFormatter:

```
const val CORRESPONDENCE_FORMAT_REGEX = "(?m)^"
const val FIRST_BODY_PART = 0

class MailFormatter
{
  fun formatPrevious(mimeMessage: MimeMessage): String
  {
    val previousMessage = mimeMessage.content
    var formattedQuote = "In reply to:\n\n"

    if (previousMessage is String)
    {
        formattedQuote += previousMessage.replace(CORRESPONDENCE_FORMAT_REGEX.toRegex(), "> ")
    }
    else if (previousMessage is MimeMultipart)
    {
        formattedQuote += (previousMessage.getBodyPart(FIRST_BODY_PART).content as String).replace(CORRESPONDENCE_FORMAT_REGEX.toRegex(), "> ")
    }

    return formattedQuote
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should not ever consider Gmail as some email formatting example. It doing non standard stuff, so same email you get in Gmail or other mail service will be formatted differently. You are free to choose your own format rule.

Comment: Alright - but I am trying to find the 'correct' format rule, since mine doesn't work :)

Comment: For plain text email it's pretty easy to just stick "> " in front of every line.  The challenge is figuring out how to handle html text.  Have you considered reading the Thunderbird code that does this?  :-)